# DidThe existing group or dataset be cleaned when opening and writing h5 file using h5py？

Tags: python, h5py

*Some data need to be written to HDF5 file in different steps, and the sample code is posted below. The problem I meet is the existing h5 group and dataset were cleaned when a new step, including opening and writing, runs again.*

```
    import h5py
    import numpy as np
    a=r"F:\HY1A1B\cd.h5"

    #first open and write
    b=h5py.File(a, 'w')
    zeroPixelCounts = np.zeros((5,10))
    QC_Attribute = b.create_group("QC Attributes")
    QC_Attribute.create_dataset("Zero Pixel Counts",(5,10),data=zeroPixelCounts)
    b.close()

    #second open and write
    b=h5py.File(a, 'w')
    QC_Attributex = b.create_group("QC Attributes xxxx")
    QC_Attributex.create_dataset("Zero Pixel Counts",(5,10),data=zeroPixelCounts)
    b.close()

    #problem：the existing data in first open and write processing were cleaned
```

Comment: AFAIK every time you use mode "w" you create a new HDF5 file.You can open in read/write/create mode with 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

I think mode "w" will always create a new HDF5 file so the second time you must open in read/write/create mode ("a", for append):

```
#second open and write
b=h5py.File(a, 'a')
```

Worked for me:

```
>>> list(b.keys())
['QC Attributes', 'QC Attributes xxxx']
```